# How can I slurp STDIN in Perl?

Tags: perl

I piping the output of several scripts.  One of these scripts outputs an entire HTML page that gets processed by my perl script.  I want to be able to pull the whole 58K of text into the perl script (which will contain newlines, of course).

I thought this might work:

```
open(my $TTY, '<', '/dev/tty');

my $html_string= do { local( @ARGV, $/ ) = $TTY ; <> } ;
```

But it just isn't doing what I need.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
my @lines = <STDIN>;
```

or

```
my $str = do { local $/; <STDIN> };
```

Comment: Should your line: `my @lines = <STDIN>;` actually be: `my $lines = <STDIN>;` ?

Comment: @KevinFegan Of course not. That will read a single line from `STDIN` by virtue of calling `readline` in scalar context.

Comment: `my $str; { local $/; $str = <STDIN> };` consumes less memory

Answer (score 8):

I can't let this opportunity to say how much I **love** [`IO::All`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO%3a%3aAll) pass without saying:

**♥ ♥ __ "I really like [`IO::All`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO%3a%3aAll) ... a lot" __ ♥ ♥**

Variation on the POD SYNOPSIS:

```
use IO::All;
my $contents < io('-') ;
print "\n printing your IO: \n $contents \n with IO::All goodness ..." ;
```

Warning:  [`IO::All`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO%3a%3aAll) may begin replacing everything else you know about IO in perl with its own insidious goodness.

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr: see at the bottom of the post. Explanation first.

### practical example

I’ve just wondered about the same, but I wanted something suitable for a shell one-liner. Turns out this is (Korn shell, whole example, dissected below):

```
print -nr -- "$x" | perl -C7 -0777 -Mutf8 -MEncode -e "print encode('MIME-Q', 'Subject: ' . <>);"; print
```

Dissecting:

- `print -nr -- "$x"` echos the whole of `$x` without any trailing newline (`-n`) or backslash escape (`-r`), POSIX equivalent: `printf '%s' "$x"`
- `-C7` sets *stdin*, *stdout*, and *stderr* into UTF-8 mode (you may or may not need it)
- `-0777` sets `$/` so that Perl will slurp the entire file; reference: man [`perlrun(1)`](https://www.mirbsd.org/man/perlrun.1)
- `-Mutf8 -MEncode` loads two modules
- the remainder is the Perl command itself: `print encode('MIME-Q', 'Subject: ' . <>);`, let’s look at it from inner to outer, right to left:

  - `<>` takes the entire *stdin* content
  - which is concatenated with the string `"Subject: "`
  - and passed to `Encode::encode` asking it to convert that to MIME Quoted-Printable
  - the result of which is printed on stdout (without any trailing newline)
- this is followed by `; print`, again in Korn shell, which is the same as `; echo` in POSIX shell – just echoïng a newline.

### tl;dr

Call `perl` with the `-0777` option. Then, inside the script, `<>` will contain the entire *stdin*.

#### complete self-contained example

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -0777
my $x = <>;
print "Look ma, I got this: '$x'\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

To get it into a single string you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $html_string;
while(<>){
   $html_string .= $_;
}

print $html_string;
```

Comment: I already knew how to get single lines.  That's why I explicitly stated "slurp" and gave an example where I turned the line termination character off.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used a bare block.

```
  my $x;
  {
    undef $/; # Set slurp mode
    $x = <>;  # Read in everything up to EOF
  }
  # $x should now contain all of STDIN
```